# Which browsers don't support empty tags?

Tags: html, intellij-idea

The [intellij linter](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Code_Inspections_in_HTML.html) throws an `Empty Tag`-warning:

> Reports empty tags (like script ) that do not work in some
>   browsers.The validation works in html or jsp file types.

Which browsers are affected by the problem? How important is it to clear that warning?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

All browsers except Netscape 4 will allow empty tags.

refer: [Is using empty tags valid in HTML5?](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/is-using-empty-tags-valid-in-html5/35629/6)

Answer (score 0):

Original issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-2582 claims that empty `<script>` tag wasn't supported by Internet Explorer.

Later it was enhanced to support `<div>`/`<iframe>` tags. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-5167